# How to config Prettier to line break className attribute in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier

This is the original code with Prettier applied:

```
<div
  role="menubar"
  className="absolute top-0 left-0 z-50 h-0 mt-10 grid grid-cols-3 gap-x-3 gap-y-5 "
>
</div>
```

This is my expected code result:

```
<div
  role="menubar"
  className="absolute top-0 left-0 z-50 
             h-0 mt-10 grid grid-cols-3 
             gap-x-3 gap-y-5 "
>
</div>
```

Could anyone recommend the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [Print Width](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) attribute in prettier.

It allows you to specify after how many letters the line should wrap.